# Subtract two values in different columns depending on column values

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame that looks something like this:

```
df =

          AT       BE       DE       FR       NL       from     to
id
10365     2        4        6        12       4        DE       AT
10366     3        6        7        14       7        AT       FR
10370     4        8        8        16       10       BE       FR
10370     5        10       9        18       13       BE       FR
10380     6        12       10       20       16       NL       DE
```

What I would like to do is get another column with two values from the columns subtracted from each other, if it matches the `from` `to` values. I.e. the resulting data frame should be something like:

```
df_result =

          AT       BE       DE       FR       NL       from     to    result
id
10365     2        4        6        12       4        DE       AT    6-2 = 4
10366     3        6        7        14       7        AT       FR    3-14 = -11
10370     4        8        8        16       10       BE       FR    8-16 = -8
10370     5        10       9        18       13       BE       FR    10-18 = -8
10380     6        12       10       20       16       NL       DE    16-10 = 6
```

No need for the calculations of course.

Hence, first row with `from = DE` and `to = AT` it should subtract the value for `AT` in that row from the value in `DE` for the same row etc.

Comment: You need to perform a `lookup` on both columns, then a simple subtraction. See duplicate for the lookup.

Answer (score 0):

Using Lambda

```
df['result'] = df.apply(lambda x: x[x['from']]-x[x['to']], axis=1)
```